# apt-get update getting 404 on debian lenny

Tags: apt, debian-lenny

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free

###### Debian Update Repos
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
```

When I do:

```
# apt-get update
```

I'm getting some good lines, then:

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/contrib Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/non-free Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny-proposed-updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny-proposed-updates/contrib Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny-proposed-updates/non-free Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny-proposed-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny-proposed-updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny-proposed-updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 35.9.37.225 80]    
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a little poking around, it appears to be a problem with the Debian mirrors.  According to the mirror info, lenny should be available, although you might need to change each instance of 'lenny' with 'oldstable' in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  However, pulling up 3 mirrors have all shown that 'lenny' and 'oldstable' are no longer listed.

**Update:** I did a little more poking around, and found that the [USC Mirror](ftp://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/debian/dists/) looks to still have 'lenny' listed.  Comment out your existing entries in `sources.list` and duplicate them the:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/
```

Replaced with:

```
deb ftp://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/debian/
```

See if that does the trick.

With a little luck this is a temporary issue, and will resolve itself in a few days.

**Update 2:** It looks like this is not temporary, and http://archive.debian.org is the best place to pull packages for Lenny.  Also, it looks like security support for Lenny was ended on Feb. 12th 2012, although they did release 5.0.10, a point update, on March 10th, 2012.

It would probably be worth planning out an upgrade, especially for any Internet/public facing servers.

Comment: Thanks! What about "security.debian.org"?

Comment: I also found http://serverfault.com/questions/373314/debian-5-0-lenny-apt-sources-fail

Comment: Good catch.  I'll update my answer with a few details from that, in case anyone comes across it here.

Comment: Why are you saying it's temporary?  It seems like it's EOL.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "problem with the mirrors" that they've stopped carrying a release that's no longer supported.

Comment: The comment about it being temporary in the second update was in error; it was supposed to read 'this is likely **not** temporary'.  I'm fixing it now.

Answer (score 29):

modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 2):

> Lenny packages have been removed from all mirrors to: archive.debian.org
>   So update your sources.list to:
>   deb http://archive.debian.org lenny main contrib

OK - that ddn't work for me, but

```
 deb http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib
```

did