# Install ZIP in Debian

Tags: debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get update getting 404 on debian lenny](https://serverfault.com/questions/374651/apt-get-update-getting-404-on-debian-lenny)

I Have search that the command for install zip in debian is

apt-get install zip

I tried so many time.
The result is like this.

```
Err http://ftp.jp.debian.org lenny/main unzip 5.52-12
  404 Not Found
Err http://ftp.jp.debian.org lenny/main zip 2.32-1
  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_5.52-12_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/z/zip/zip_2.32-1_i386.deb  404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Lenny is not officially supported any more. The official repositories have been discontinued.

Comment: You could always build it from source ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am just a beginner.  what do you mean by (You could always build it from source)

Comment: "sudo apt-get update" and then try againtry

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be "zip", but instead something that supports .zip files, you could always give [p7zip](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/p7zip/p7zip/9.20.1/p7zip_9.20.1_x86_linux_bin.tar.bz2?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/9.20.1/&ts=1354064109&use_mirror=ignum) a go.

Also worth a try would be the equivalent-ish [packages for zip](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/3324430/zip_2.32-1_i386.deb) from Ubuntu 8.04.  Unzip [can be found here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/edgy/i386/unzip/5.52-8ubuntu1.1) too.

They're identical versions to the ones mentioned in the question for Debian, and I've generally found that for things like this, Debian and Ubuntu are pretty closely interchangeable.

If you find the .deb file doesn't work, you could always go looking inside it for the zip and unzip binaries, with

```
ar vx path/to/file.deb
```

then `tar xzvf data.tar.gz` and then see if you can find the files from inside the debian package.

Comment: thanks for the p7zip.  But I think I should find the i136 version.                                                        　　　　　　　　　　                       　　　raigo:/home/media/ogura# dpkg -i zip_3.0-3_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing zip_3.0-3_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zip_3.0-3_amd64.deb

Comment: I found it here and it works. thanks guys. http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/p7zip/download